# Install Silverlight OOB app from within another Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob, elevated-privileges

I have a big LOB Silverlight App that works in browser and now I need to do smth with elevated priveleges so I need to install smth OOB. But I don't want to install whole app with all its complexity and assumptions - I'd want to have a small separate Silverlight app that I'll be able to install from within main one. Any ideas on how can I incorporate one Silverlight app with ability to install it OOB within another Silverlight app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explanation is going to seem a lot like the movie Inception: a Silverlight within a Silverlight.

First of all, even with a trusted Silverlight 4 out of browser application you have [restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#native_integration) around the file system that make executing the sllauncher (the program that runs your oob apps can also be used at the command line to uninstall/install them) to do an install impossible, but there are two other possibilities you could explore:

1. Embed the WebBrowser class in your out-of-browser app and point it to a website with an installable out of browser app.  I tried this and it in fact works.  Remember that you will only be able to prompt them to install the app from the second website; there is no way to force an install on a user through the web.
2. There may be a COM API you could use to execute sllauncher while pointing it at a XAP file you download through normal Silverlight APIs.  To do the COM part of this would require a trusted signed app though.  I cannot think of a COM object to launch sllauncher off hand though so that may be a good question to ask eleswhere.  I have not tried this approach.

Comment: Hm.. I think you misunderstood me: I have big SL app in browser and I want to install small one from within this big one so that it will run OOB. As WebBrowser isn't available while in browser and COM isn't available either I doubt it's possible to accomplish this way.

Comment: Okay.   Take the same premise of embedded HTML content and use hosted HTML within your in-browser app: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/09/19/hosting-html-in-silverlight-not-out-of-browser.aspx